# Django query for ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True, related_name = 'user')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null = True, blank = True)

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    price = models.FloatField(default = 0)
```

I've:

```
p1 = Product.objects.get(pk = 1)
```

I want to count how many times `p1` is contained in `likes` field in all UserProfile objects.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(likes=p1).count()
```

assuming that a product can only be liked one time by each profile.